# Getting exit code on the remote server after jump through a bastion

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I would like to get the exit code of my remote command.
It's normally pretty easy, but I need to execute my command through a bastion host and I don't know take that with a easy methode.

So, this is a diagram of my architecture.

```
PC => Bastion => remote host
```

I used this code to execute my command and check the return code:

```
ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -At ubuntu@$ip_bastion ssh -Aq -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null ubuntu@$ip_server bash <<EOF
{ ${cmd} ; } 2>&1 | sed  -e 's/^/$(colors_next exec)$region:$ip:$type${normal} /'
EOF
echo $?
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    error "Error during the command execution."
    exit 1
fi
```

But, the return code is always equal 0, while my command failed (Return 255 on the final server).

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using bash, you can use the PIPESTATUS array variable to get the exit status of each element of the pipeline.

```
ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -At ubuntu@$ip_bastion ssh -Aq -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null ubuntu@$ip_server bash <<EOF
{ ${cmd} ; } 2>&1 | sed  -e 's/^/$(colors_next exec)$region:$ip:$type${normal} /'
exit "\${PIPESTATUS[0]}"
EOF
remote_exitcode=$?
echo "remote_exitcode=${remote_exitcode}"
if [[ ${remote_exitcode} -ne 0 ]]; then
    error "Error during the command execution."
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I tried, but ${PIPESTATUS[0]} always returns 0 and ${PIPESTATUS[1]} returns void. it's weird...

Comment: Oh my bad, I had made a mistake when I copied it. Thank you it was the solution:)

Answer (score 0):

The `echo` command is hurting you.  You need to capture the value of `$?` before echoing it, because `echo` will reset it to 0, assuming that the `echo` command is successful.

```
ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -At ubuntu@$ip_bastion ssh -Aq -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null ubuntu@$ip_server bash <<EOF
{ ${cmd} ; } 2>&1 | sed  -e 's/^/$(colors_next exec)$region:$ip:$type${normal} /'
EOF
rc=$?
echo $rc
if [[ $rc -ne 0 ]]; then
    error "Error during the command execution."
    exit 1
fi
```

Optionally, you may want to `exit $rc` so that your script exits with the same return code that your SSH command exited with, which might in some cases be helpful in figuring out what went wrong.

Comment: yeah, I had already tried that, but the rc variable always returns the value 0. I think, it's because of the first ssh connection that's done correctly.

Comment: I think I see the problem. this line always returns 0 : ```{ ${cmd} ; } 2>&1 | sed  -e 's/^/$(colors_next exec)$region:$ip:$type${normal} /'```. I don't see how to catch the $cmd return code.

Comment: Regardless of that fact, you still *have* to capture the `$?` value before you echo it, or `echo` will override it.  The later answer also uses that technique.  Test it and see for yourself: `false; echo $?; echo $?`